# Force mixed line endings in ViM

Tags: vim, newline, line-endings

I have a Python file that is developed under Windows, so it naturally has CR LF line endings. I added the Python shebang on it using `#!/usr/bin/env python3` to make it directly executable under Linux. The loader prints out an error message:

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘python3\r’: No such file or directory
```

I know I can simply execute the file using `python3 x.py`, but for various reasons I want to have it with the `#!` on the first line.

My current solution is to have the first line in a separate file that has Unix line endings, and use `cat prefix.py x.py > y.py` to generate an executable with mixed line endings. But I would prefer to have the first line being handled differently by ViM. Is that possible?

If I edit `y.py` I get a `^M` on each but the first line since this is a mixed line endings file, so a solution for me would be to not display the `^M` and use DOS line endings everywhere, but keep the UNIX line ending on the first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The easy and obvious solution is to run dos2unix on the python script
> and strip out the insidious \r character.
>
> The hackish solution is to create a symlink literally named
> /usr/local/bin/python^M which points to /usr/local/bin/python. This
> will let you run all such python scripts in the future without running
> dos2unix on them first.

Source: https://natanyellin.com/posts/shebang-python-bad-interpreter-m/